# How to set xAxis only with time in Highstock step graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any possibility to set the xAxis of the Highstock graph to display only the time?

Here it shows both date and time and I need to display only time:

[image: highstock graph image]

Thanks in advance.

```
$(function () {

    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container1', {
        chart: {
        width: 500,
        height: 300
        },
        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
         xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1
    },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4,
            inputEnabled: false,
            buttonTheme: {
                visibility: 'hidden'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                visibility: 'hidden'
            }
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: false
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: [45,90,90,45,50,90,39,50,90,39],
            step: true,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
        Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
            chart: {
            width: 500,
            height: 300
            },
            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
             xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',  
                tickInterval : 1,
                dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                    day: '%M min'
                }
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 0,
                inputEnabled: false,
                buttonTheme: {
                    visibility: 'hidden'
                },
                labelStyle: {
                    visibility: 'hidden'
                }
            },
            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data: [45,90,90,45,50,90,39,50,90,39],
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
                pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 , 
                step: true,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
});
```

Comment: Tried...! this but no change on xAxis.

Comment: Still no change

Comment: can you please provide me full image of your graph ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/

Comment: where is the date in this graph ?

Comment: in that i dint provide the date. but instead of this '00:00:00.001' i need only time , say a 15min interval

Comment: plz check this link

Comment: Wel come , I am always happy to helps others.